# Are there any reliable sources with more frequent jdk icedtea package releases?

Tags: java, openjdk, jdk, icedtea

I use the canonical repository for retrieving updates from the  jdk icedtea, but it seems that it is lagging a lot behind what is supposed to be the latest stable version as per the icedtea website (mine is 2.3.10 while the latest one is 2.4.3 from october).

Is there any other reliable repository from which I can get more recent icedtea packages for ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software)

Comment: sorry if I may disagree, but I am not asking why there is a delay but rather what are the other repository options in order to get the icedtea openjdk more up to date

Comment: Exactly. This looks like a valid question and not a duplicate of that one. I think we should leave it open.

Comment: If it's not a duplicate of that question , it's certainly a duplicate of another. The options are 1) find a PPA or other archive with the packages, 2) make your own PPA with the packages, 3) build from source.

Comment: some good suggestions of PPAs could solve my problem. When searching I basically found [this](https://launchpad.net/~openjdk/+archive/ppa) and [this](https://launchpad.net/~no1wantdthisname/+archive/openjdk-fontfix) which are quite outdated.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are willing to compile from sources for yourself or setting up an PPA to share with others in a regular manner, no, there isn't any *reliable* and secure way to get the latest version of *any* package. Ubuntu is based in stability rather than cutting edge. Security patches has priority in Ubuntu releases so there's nothing to be afraid. Now if you want to have the latest features, Ubuntu release aren't designed for that and you need the developers, third party or yourself as reliable source.

Mandatory read:

- [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software)